# asp.net mvc Anchor Tag Helpers generates html "id" is part of the query string ,not part of the route data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
     }
     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseRouting();

     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions {
         MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
     });

     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
         endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "default",
              pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });
}
```

CustomerController.cs

URL: /customer/details/7

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id) {
    var model = GetUser();
    return View(model);
}
```

After adding the following code
(get the detailed information of the currently logged in customer)

URL: /customer/details

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details() {
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    return await Details(userId);
}
```

Anchor Tag Helpers generates  html "id" is part of the query string ,not part of the route data.

```
<a  asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Customer" asp-route-id="@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name">User Details</a>
```

It generates this HTML:

```
<a  href="/Customer/Details?id=1">User Details</a>
```

How to still generates  HTML :

```
<a  href="/Customer/Details/1">User Details</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Jared, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you also post your Startup.cs?

Comment: I have posted Startup.cs  Configure Method . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 1: Your default routing template is

```
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
         endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "default",
              pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });
```

Point 2: If you put a routing directly to your controller action this will override the default routing since your two action has the same name, you need to also add a routing to the other one. Check the below code, this is.

**SOLUTION 1**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Route("[controller]/[action]/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id) {
    var model = GetUser();
    return View(model);
}
```

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details() {
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    return await Details(userId);
}
```

Point 3: If you can change the action name of the other controller then you can go with this approach. Just rename the action which has no routing directly on it.

**SOLUTION 2**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details2(int id) {
    var model = GetUser();
    return View(model);
}
```

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details() {
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    return await Details(userId);
}
```